# I would like Appendices to be listed separately from the main table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titletoc, appendix

I want my table of contents to look like the included image where the appendices are listed separately from everything else.

I would also like to know how to remove the excess space between the table of contents title "Contents" and also change the size of font.

Thank you

Here is my Sample Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\graphicspath{{<path to images>}}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\bf}
\geometry{a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}
\begin{document}
     \tableofcontents
     \chapter{Heading 1}
     \section{Heading 2}
     \subsection{Heading 3}
\end{document}
```

[image: Desired format of table of contents]

Comment: Use the `tocloft` package for spacing and font changes. It also lets you set up a new "List of Appendices". Read the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the package `appendix`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setmainfont{calibri}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\bfseries}
\geometry{a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}

\usepackage[toc,titletoc]{appendix} % added <<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Heading 1}
    \section{Heading 2}
    \subsection{Heading 3}
    \chapter*{References}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}% added <<<<<<<<<<

    \begin{appendices}  
        \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}% added <<<<<<<<<<  
        \chapter{Name of Appendix I}
        \chapter{Name of Appendix II}   
    \end{appendices}    
        
\end{document}
```

"References" is an unnumbered chapter so `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}` adds it to the ToC.

`\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}` after  `\begin{appendices}`  changes the default alphabetical format for appendix to numeric.

`\usepackage[toc,titletoc]{appendix}`

The option `toc` put a header (e.g., "Appendices") into the Table of Contents before listing the appendices.

The option `titletoc` Adds a name (e.g., "Appendix") before each appendix listed in the ToC.

You may want to add also the option `page` to insert a single page titled `Appendices` to separate the numerical numbered appendices from  the chapters.

Or put before the appendices

`\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{Appendix ~\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge\bfseries}`

to get

[image: b]

**UPDATE** After follow-up question

Add dotted lines for chapter level and un-bold everthing except "Contents" and Appendices titles.

Done using the package `titletoc`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setmainfont{calibri}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\bfseries}
\geometry{a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm}

%****************************************************************
\usepackage[toc,titletoc, page]{appendix} % added <<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{titletoc}  % added <<<<<<<<<<
\titlecontents{chapter}
[0pt]{}{\thecontentslabel \quad}{}{\titlerule*[0.75em]{.}\contentspage}[\addvspace{.5pc}]
\titlecontents{section}
[3.8em]{}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}{\hspace*{-2.3em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\addvspace{.5pc}]
\titlecontents{subsection}
[4.3em]{}{\contentslabel{2.8em}}{\hspace*{-2.8em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\addvspace{.5pc}]
%****************************************************************

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Heading 1}
    \section{Heading 2}
    \subsection{Heading 3}
    \chapter*{References}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}% added <<<<<<<<<<

    \begin{appendices}  
        \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}% added <<<<<<<<<<  
        \titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{Appendix ~\thechapter}{20pt}{\huge\bfseries}
        \titlecontents{chapter}% bold title in ToC <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        [0pt]{}{\thecontentslabel \quad\bfseries}{}{\titlerule*[0.75em]{.}\contentspage}[\addvspace{.5pc}]
        \chapter{Name of Appendix I}
        \chapter{Name of Appendix II}   
    \end{appendices}    
        
\end{document}
```

[image: c]

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I needed ! 
Just a small thing though 
1) how do I get the dotted lines for "References" ?
2) How do I unbold everything except the "contents" and Appendices titles ?

Comment: @Aurelius_nero Please the the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you somuch!